# git clone: fatal: destination path already exists and is not an empty directory (not related to leftover files)

Tags: linux, git

I'm learning about Arch Linux packaging. I am confused by the following error:

```
Creating working copy of git repo...
fatal: destination path already exists and is not an empty directory.
ERROR: Failure while creating working copy of git repo
```

This is not related to leftover files in the directory. That seems to be the common reason for this error. However, I get the error even if I start with a completely empty directory. I have looked at all the similar questions here, and I don't think this is a duplicate of any of them.

Could this be related to the fact that my project name is the same as a filename in the project? I have seen other projects that use this convention, such as: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chaptedit/ . (Github url: https://github.com/helixarch/chaptedit).

My repo name is `myproject`, my project name is `myproject`, and the executable file is named `myproject`. I looked through [Arch package guidelines](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_sources) and did not find anything addressing this issue. I prefer to keep the executable file name as it is.

Here is the exact error:

```
$ cd myproject

$ git pull

remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 315.00 KiB/s, done.
From xxx/test1
3409aa3..55afd12  master     -> origin/master
Updating 8309ab3..77afd12
Fast-forward
PKGBUILD | 2 +-
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ makepkg -s
==> Making package: myproject 1.0-1 (Mon 05 Oct 2020 08:15:52 PM EDT)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
-> Cloning myproject git repo...
Cloning into bare repository 'path/myproject'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 52, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (52/52), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Total 52 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (52/52), 4.45 MiB | 3.67 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), done.
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    myproject ... validated
==> Extracting sources...
-> Creating working copy of myproject git repo...
fatal: destination path 'myproject' already exists and is not an empty directory.
==> ERROR: Failure while creating working copy of myproject git repo
    Aborting...
```

Comment: looks like you set your project as a dependency of itself

Comment: @Ôrel - I did not  list `myproject` in the `depends=` array of `PKGBUILD`. Is there something else that would cause this?

Comment: is it working without `-s` ?

Comment: @Ôrel - the result is the same with or without `-s`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Existing folder as future AUR package-Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214132)

> Is it possible to have a working and already populated directory and submit as AUR package?

Yes, it is, but in my case I was caught by some poor naming choices.

I saved my local source code files in a subdirectory named `src` in my project while **also** having a source file of the same name as the project name. That will not work*.

**Non-working example:**

```
project name: foo
source file name: foo
source directory name: src
```

* I did not find any way to make it work with these names. If there is one, please provide answer here.

However, changing any one of those names will eliminate the conflict.

Solutions I tested include include:

1. don't have a source code file of same name as project. Change filename `foo` to `foo.sh` for example.
2. do not use a subdirectory named `src` to hold those source files. Change directory name to `source` for example
3. do not have any source files in the directory at all. `makepkg` can pull needed source from a remote repo if a local PKGBUILD file exists.

I selected option 2: I used `git mv` to rename `src/` to `source/`. Problem solved.